# Class B constructor argument is an interface.I need to pass as an argument to the 4th generation successor constructor of this interface

Tags: java, antlr4

There are two lines:

1. An instance of the class 'ANTLRInputStream' is created as 'input';
2. An instance of another LabLexer class is created as 'lexer', where the 'input' object from the previous line is passed in the constructor;
   The 'lexer' constructor specifies that the input argument type is CharStream, but CharStream is an interface. This interface implements the 'ANTLRStringStream' class. The latter has a successor - 'ANTLReaderStream', and it has 'ANTLRInputStream' from the first line.
   Problem Description: "LabLexer(org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream)" in "LabLexer" cannot be applied to "(org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream)"
   Unfortunately, I can't change the code, since it's a rather complicated tool for me - the code is written "according to the instructions."
   Help please!

I tried to change the type of variable - not successful.
And add new constructor or change existing - not successful too (variable of CharStream type is initialized in begin of code).
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post all code as *text* rather than images. (I note this isn't the first time you've received this feedback, by the way...)

Answer (score -1):

The `ANTLRInputStream` class is an ANTLR v3 class. You need the v4 variant(s). Do something like this instead:

```java
CharStream charStream = args.length > 0
    ? CharStreams.fromFileName(args[0])
    : CharStreams.fromStream(System.in);

LabLexer lexer = new LabLexer(charStream);
LabParser parser = new LabParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
```

Comment: And it's too, thank you!)

Answer (score -1):

It's funny, but I quickly found a solution
The type of the variable must be the name of the interface.
Char input = new ANTLRInputStream(arg); instead of ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(arg);
Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm new to Java))

Comment: The v4 version of `ANTLRInputStream` is deprecated: do not use it, go for my suggestion instead.